Problem with a command into Sed
This following code should outputs theString
LANG=C ; 
echo 'aString12 theString34 otherString56' | \
sed "s;aString12 \(theString34\) anotherString56;$(printf '%s' "\1" | sed 's;[0-9]\{2\}$;;');"

...but it outputs theString34. The 34 should be eliminated by | sed 's;[0-9]{2}$;;'); but it doesn't.
I need to fix this by changing the part $(printf '%s' "\1" | sed 's;[0-9]\{2\}$;;') only and it shouldn't be solved by replacing that part of code with a variable.
Thanks in advance.

Just FYI, you don't need \  to break a line after a |, you can just break on the | directly.

Can't say I can make sense of what you want to do. Maybe you should provide a more representative example of what you want to do. In any case, using perl as in perl -pe 's{aString12 (theString34) otherString56}{$1 =~ s/\d{2}$//r}e' may make things easier.

Your issue is that the embedded command substitution is executed even before the sed command is started.  It is executed by the shell when it figures out what arguments to call sed with.
Instead of trying to call external utilities from within sed, you can isolate the part of the string that you need to work with, and then modify it with a second substitution command:
echo 'aString12 theString34 otherString56' |
sed -e 's/aString12 \(theString34\) otherString56/\1/' \
    -e 's/[0-9]\{2\}$//'

This replaces the whole line with the captured part in the first expression and then applies the second substitution to whatever is left in the buffer.
To only apply the second substitution if the first one did something, you may first try to match the expression, and branch to the end of the script if it doesn't match (with !b).  If it did match, you apply both substitutions:
echo 'aString12 theString34 otherString56' |
sed -e '/aString12 \(theString34\) otherString56/!b' \
    -e 's//\1/' \
    -e 's/[0-9]\{2\}$//'

The empty regular expression in the first substitution (s//\1/) will reuse the most recently matched pattern, i.e. the one from the previous expression.

Not clear why the OP can't just do sed 's/aString12 \(theString\)34 otherString56/\1/' here. Or for that matters sed 's/aString12 theString34 otherString56/theString/'

@StéphaneChazelas I'm assuming that in their real application, theString is not actually known.
